# Python class structure and inheritage

Tags: python

I am pretty new to Python, and I am trying to work out the relationships between classes and inheritage etc.

Let's say that I have a class `Student`:

```
class Student():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

This student can attend multiple courses:

```
class Course():
     def __init__(self, title):
         self.title = title

     def get_title(self):
         return self.title

     def set_title(self, title):
         self.title = title
```

And for each course there can also be multiple students.
So it's a `manyToMany` relationship.
My first thought is to create a third class called `StudentCourse`:

```
class StudentCourse(Student, Course):

     student_courses = {}

     def __init__(self, student, course):
         self.student = student
         self.course = course

     def add_student_to_course(self, student, course, results):
         self.student_courses[student] = {
             'course': course,
             'results': results
         }

     def get_student_courses(self, student):
         return self.student_courses.get(student)
```

Is this the correct structure? 
If so, my question is: within the Student class, how do I access the `student_courses` dictionary containing the particular student's courses and results?

**EDIT**
I want to be able to see which students attend a specific course, as well as get the results for each individual student attending a course.

Looking forward to your responses.

Comment: Do you have an example of how you're trying to use this?

Comment: Usually you would keep a list of Courses in each Student instead of making a StudentCourse class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of an opinion-based question than something that you can get a clear answer to. That being said, given that both `Student` and `Course` are two very different entities, being connected only by *ownership*, there is no point in creating a muxed class out of the two.

Instead, I'd recommend having them both handle their part of the many-to-many relationship in a double-linked fashion, i.e. when you add a `Student` to a `Course`, you also *inform* the `Student` that they now are part of that course and vice versa. Something like:

```
class Student(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.courses = {}  # we'll use a dict so that our courses can be mapped to results

    def add_course(self, course):
        if course not in self.courses:
            self.courses[course] = {}  # initialize each course with an empty dict
            # feel free to use any fields you like, like results etc.
            course.add_student(self)

    def del_course(self, course):
        self.courses.pop(course, None)
        course.del_student(self)

    def __repr__(self):  # just to ease our printouts
        return self.name
```

And:

```
class Course(object):

    def __init__(self, title):
        self.title = title
        self.students = set()  # a set ought to be enough

    def add_student(self, student):
        self.students.add(student)
        student.add_course(self)

    def del_student(self, student):
        self.students.discard(student)
        student.del_course(self)

    def __repr__(self):  # just to ease our printouts
        return self.title
```

And then you can use them in both directions to establish your many-to-many relationship, e.g.:

```
# Create some students and courses
john = Student("John Doe")
jane = Student("Jane Doe")
foo = Course("Foo Course")
bar = Course("Bar Course")
```

And then:

```
# initial state
print("John courses: {}".format(john.courses))  # John courses: {}
print("Jane courses: {}".format(jane.courses))  # Jane courses: {}
print("Foo students: {}".format(foo.students))  # Foo students: set([])
print("Bar students: {}".format(bar.students))  # Bar students: set([])

# lets add John to Foo:
john.add_course(foo)
print("John courses: {}".format(john.courses))  # John courses: {Foo Course: {}}
print("Foo students: {}".format(foo.students))  # Foo students: set([John Doe])

# lets add Jane to Bar, the other way around
bar.add_student(jane)
print("Jane courses: {}".format(jane.courses))  # Jane courses: {Bar Course: {}}
print("Bar students: {}".format(bar.students))  # Bar students: set([Jane Doe])

# lets add John to Bar as well
bar.add_student(john)
print("John courses: {}".format(john.courses))
# John courses: {Foo Course: {}, Bar Course: {}}
print("Bar students: {}".format(bar.students))
# Bar students: set([Jane Doe, John Doe])

# finally, lets add some info for the Foo course to John
john.courses[foo]["results"] = 94
print("John courses: {}".format(john.courses))
# John courses: {Foo Course: {'results': 94}, Bar Course: {}}
```

And given that we use native structures - sets and dictionaries - to hold our relationships not only that we automatically guard against duplicated entries, we can also easily (and very fast) check for relationships, too, e.g.:

```
print("John is in Bar: {}".format(john in bar.students))  # John is in Bar: True
# or:
print("Bar is in John's courses: {}".format(bar in john.courses))
# Bar is in John's courses: True

print("Jane is in Foo: {}".format(jane in foo.students))  # Jane is in Foo: False
```

Then you can expand on it, e.g. to formalize the results you're storing and similar structures - you can continue developing the API to suit your needs. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Inheritance is almost certainly the wrong way to express the relationship between `Student`s and `Course`s. Inheritance indicates an IS-A relationship. Neither your students are courses, nor are your courses students. So IS-A is wrong.

What you probably want is HAS-A. Each `Student` HAS-A number of `Course`s they're enrolled in. Similarly, each `Course` has several `Student`s enrolled. In a database you'd create relationship object to handle the many-to-many relationship, but in Python code you can use data structures instead. A list is a natural pick. Here's a design that adds a list of courses to each student and a list of students to each course:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.courses = []

    def enroll(self, course):
        self.courses.append(course)
        course.students.append(self)

class Course():
    def __init__(self, title):
        self.title = title
        self.students = []

    def enroll_student(self, student):
        student.enroll(self)
```

A note about getters and setters (unrelated to your main question): You usually don't need to write methods like `get_name` and `set_name` in Python. Usually you should just use the attribute directly if those methods are not doing anything (like validating the input or translating the output in some way). In other languages it is often a best practice to always write and use such methods even if you don't need them yet, but in Python, if you later decide you do need to do some validation, you can change the implementation of the attribute lookup into a method call using a `property`.

Comment: Ok, that makes great sense! Thanks for posting that.
How about the students' grades for each individual course: `results` - in which class would you store that?

Comment: You could turn one of the lists into a dictionary, mapping from student to grade, for instance (or from course to grade, if you put it in the student object). Or you could bring back the idea of the relationship object, where the grade could live alongside a reference to the student and course. There is not just one way to solve the problem.